# Application Sub Main

Tags: .net, startup, program-entry-point

I've created an .Net application. Now I wanted to include a *application crashed - I am sorry messagebox*. But I cannot find any `Sub Main()` routine or even if I create my new own module I am not able to selecte the `Sub Main()` in the module as startobject.

Any advice?

[image: Application Sub Main]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create a **VB.NET** application? If so, you'll need to add your *own* `Sub Main()`. The disadvantage of this, however, is that you'll have to manually handle all of the startup processing and initialization that the .NET Framework normally does for you automatically.

But if all you want to do is show an error message when an unhandled exception occurs, there's no reason to create your own `Sub Main()`. All you have to do is add a handler for the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I found the key because of your answer which was ` Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain`
   `AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler`